# Not able save node in neo4j and two nodes showing same node id

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am getting below mention error while saving a user in neo4j.
neo4j - 2.1.5
SDN - 3.2.2

and also multiple nodes are showing same node id.[image]

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error executing statement match (n) where id(n)={nodeId} set n:`User`:`_User`; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error executing statement match (n) where id(n)={nodeId} set n:`User`:`_User`; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Node 3 has been deleted
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.query.CypherQueryEngineImpl.query(CypherQueryEngineImpl.java:61) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.LabelBasedStrategyCypherHelper.setLabelsOnNode(LabelBasedStrategyCypherHelper.java:51) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Can you try to update to 3.3.0 ?

Comment: Hi Michael, most of times node creation works fine in neo4j but few times I got the above mentioned error while saving a node in neo4j.

Comment: I have 2 nodes User and UserHobby. As shown in the above image node id 10 is same for both User and UserHobby node coz of this while reading relationships from neo4j  I am converting node back to User and UserHobby, I am getting type conversion error.

Comment: Node-id can't be the same for two nodes.